# Require all status checks to pass in a protected branch for a GitHub PR

Tags: github

We are using the [Require status checks to pass before merging](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches#require-status-checks-before-merging) setting for our protected branch `main` in our GitHub monorepo. It works well for one of our checks, one that always needs to run.

However, we have other checks (in CircleCI) that are run *sometimes* for a pull request but not always. It depends on what has changed in the monorepo.

We would like to configure the protected branch so that it requires all the checks that are actually run to also pass. So if a check is run, it needs to pass.

Is this possible?

I can add all the status checks to the list of required checks in the protected branch settings. But if I do, PRs that won't run all the checks will never be considered mergeable.

This is particularly important since we would like to use the [auto-merge](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/automatically-merging-a-pull-request) setting so that you can enable the PR to merge automatically once all requirements are met. But with our current setup, the PR is considered mergeable immediately once the one required status check has run, and the PR is merged before the rest of the CI/CD pipeline has finished.

Comment: What you are looking for makes perfect sense and I want the same thing.  The GitHub branch protection settings are completely illogical: you define which workflows should run for merge requests to a target branch, and they are automatically applied to merge requests as 'Checks', but then you have to additionally specify which checks are required!!!  If the workflow runs under the specified conditions, then of course it's required!